# Unable to Run Simple Fine-Tuning of GPT-J Model

Tags: python, data-science, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I have been trying to learn to fine tune Large Language Models (LLM), specifically GPT-J from HuggingFace.  I have been struggling to make even simple examples work on custom datasets.  I wanted to train the model to produce google reviews, and was hoping to train it on some publicly available data from here: https://jiachengli1995.github.io/google/index.html

I cleaned the dataset using pandas, just by reading in the JSON file data.  I removed most of the columns except the text and the humans rating score, and then added the standard GPT <|endoftext|>, so the format in the final output file should have each row look like:

`<|endoftext|>3: This reestruarunt was pretty OK, middle of the pack<|endoftext|>`

I did this for 32000 lines and exported it to a .csv file for use as training data, the .csv file is available here: [Link to CSV File](https://collidetech-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/p/fred/ERGBiYyLz_JJttt77vk3jp4BpCtgWYuqahC7QZet40P1Yw?e=8pV2dx)

Finally, I used some tutorial code from HuggingFace to try and build a simple training pipeline in a jupyter notebook.  I have been running the notebook in a Docker container that I SSH into and it appears to run fine in that environment, but when I try and run the final block of code

```
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=small_train_dataset
)

print("Starting training")
trainer.train()
print("Finished Fine Tuning")
```

I get an error message:
`ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits,past_key_values. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.`

This seems to be related to a similar stackoverflow issue: [How to fine-tune gpt-j using Huggingface Trainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74014379/how-to-fine-tune-gpt-j-using-huggingface-trainer) , and I have tried to modify my code to fit their solution, but the issue does not seem to resolve with the use of the DataCollator function from HuggingFace.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Please find the full code below:

```py
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoModelForCausalLM
from transformers import GPTJForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from datasets import load_dataset
import time
import torch
import os
import numpy as np
import evaluate
import transformers

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("Using CUDA!!!")
    model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B", torch_dtype=torch.float16).cuda()
else:
    print("OOPS, NO CUDA")
    model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B", torch_dtype=torch.float16)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B")

#functions
def tokenize_function(examples):
    current_tokenizer_result = tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)
    return current_tokenizer_result

def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    logits, labels = eval_pred
    predictions = np.argmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return metric.compute(predictions=predictions, references=labels)

#Add a file for saving the model weights
tuned_gptj = "./tuned_models/gpt-j-6B"

#Load the dataset, using the load_dataset function
current_dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="train.csv")

model.config.pad_token_id = model.config.eos_token_id
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

#tokenize the dataset
tokenized_datasets = current_dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
small_train_dataset = tokenized_datasets["train"].select(range(24000))

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir=tuned_gptj,
                                 report_to='all',
                                 logging_dir='./logs',
                                 per_device_train_batch_size=1,
                                 label_names=['input_ids','attention_mask'],
                                 num_train_epochs=1,
                                 no_cuda=False,
                                 deepspeed='ds_config_stage1.json'
                                 )
metric = evaluate.load("accuracy")

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=small_train_dataset
)

print("Starting training")
trainer.train()
print(f"Finished fine-tuning in {time.time() - start}")
```

Comment: We do not accept colab links, code has to be in the question as text, not as an external link.

Comment: Hey @Dr.Snoopy thanks for letting me know, I have gone back and added the entire code at the bottom and removed the colab link as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you shared, it looks like the only inputs being provided to the model are `input_ids` and `attention_mask`. The GPT-J model in `transformers` requires the `labels` argument to be passed to the `forward` function in order to compute and output the loss. Here is the relevant code in `transformers`: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.30.1/src/transformers/models/gptj/modeling_gptj.py#L879-L890

You might try adding a column called `labels` to the tokenized dataset. The value of this column should be a copy of the `input_ids` column produced by your `tokenize_function()`. You can see an example of this in the `run_clm.py` example in the `transformers` repo: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/language-modeling/run_clm.py#L502

Hope this helps.